# UNITY JSON to Object mapping error

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

So i have this string that callback function gives which contains all the json data

```
  private string jsonResponse = @"{""players""[{""name"":""cc"",""rank"":29}, ...]}";
```

And when i try to convert it from json to object using JsonUtility.FromJson it throws

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I've created object classes(root and normal class) and it still doesn't work, here is the code:

```
void actionTest(int i, string s)
     {
         Debug.Log(i + " " + s);
         Rootobject rootObj = new Rootobject();
         rootObj = JsonUtility.FromJson<Rootobject>(s);
         Debug.Log(rootObj.players.Count);
     }
 [System.Serializable]
 public class Rootobject
 {
     public List<Player> players { get; set; }
 }
 [System.Serializable]
 public class Player
 {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int rank { get; set; }
 }
```

This all happens when a button is pressed!

Answer (score 1):

This is a NullReferenceException meaning that one of your fields is NULL, can you actually post at which line exactly you are getting the exception ? if its this one

```
rootObj = JsonUtility.FromJson<Rootobject>(s);
```

Then its probably s that is NULL at this time ? also it could be that RootObject have a constructor that is triggering a NullReferenceException,
You don't have to construct rootObj since JsonUtility.FromJson will construct the item, if you want to populate your item, you can use JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite